# Is it possible to configure a Next.js application to automatically add IPTC data on all website images by customizing the Image Optimization step?

Tags: next.js, metadata, sharp, iptc

I have a Next.js 13 website running with proprietary images.

Some of them have [IPTC](https://www.iptc.org/standards/photo-metadata/) Photo Metadata but [Next.js Image optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization) by default is removing them.

Is it possible to customize Next.js app to keep them or even better to add a predefined set of IPTC metadata on all images of the website by customizing the optimization step?

I tried to look in [Next.js Image Component API](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) documentation
I see that [sharp can read IPTC Metadata](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-input#metadata) so I imagine it could be possible to customize the image optimization step to add IPTC metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current version of Next.js (13.1.1) it is not possible to keep Image [IPTC](https://www.iptc.org/standards/photo-metadata/) metadata with [image optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization).

- It is possible to turn off [optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized) per image or for all images to keep original file metadata.
- Another possibility is to manually create [different sizes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#device-sizes) of the image and use a cutom [loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader) to serve them.
- If the goal is to have images [IPTC metadata in Google indexation](https://iptc.org/standards/photo-metadata/quick-guide-to-iptc-photo-metadata-and-google-images) it is possible to use [Google structured data](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#withmetadata) in pages where the images are used.

Sharp can be used to keep image metadata using [withMetadata()](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/image-license-metadata/#add-metadata).
You can vote for this [feature request here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39249).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but it looks like you could use [the next/image `unoptimized` parameter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized) to avoid all processing of the image, which presumably would leave the metadata in-place.

Integrating support via Sharp's withMetadata() function [has been suggested](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39249) but not built. I suggest that you add your vote to the issue if you would like to see it added to next/image. I just did!

Comment: Yes (I tested it) you can use the unoptimized property for image, in this case it will keep the metadata in place but you loose the srcset generation and image api usage. One possible alternative could be to manually generate all the [desired sizes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#device-sizes) for the image and use a custom loader to reference them but this is only viable for a couple of images.
Best would be to have an option in image optimizer, I upvoted for the [the idea](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39249) thanks for the link.